# Hibernate. PSQLException: bad value for type int : admin

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, postgresql

Well I have a desktop application with JAVA and Hibernate **4.3.1**. For now I have just two entities (User and Role).

### User

```
...

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "fk_role")
private Role fk_role;

...
```

### Role

```
...

@Column(name = "admin", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BooleanType")
private boolean admin = false;

...
```

I have tried instead

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BooleanType")
```

this.

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
```

and

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.YesNoType")
```

and

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType")
```

As shown here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic

And nothing. =/

I tried this too: http://alenovarini.wikidot.com/mapping-a-custom-type-in-hibernate

=(
    In the database, the type for column admin is boolean and I use Postgres **9.3**.
    When I run this, I got the following:
    --

```
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1869)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at com.print.model.schemaPublic.gateway.UserGateway.list(UserGateway.java:61)
    at com.print.model.schemaPublic.UserBusiness.list(UserBusiness.java:22)
    at com.print.controller.MenuController.fileNovoAction(MenuController.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.library.core.ActionListenerDelegate.actionPerformed(ActionListenerDelegate.java:48)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: bad value for type int: admin**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally I found the error!

The error message that Hibernate was returning to me was "bad value for type int: admin", but that was **not** the problem. This message was completely crazy in relation to the issue. **The real problem was that in the database my primary key (pk_role) is a VARCHAR type, but in my entity I put as an INTEGER type.**

After Vlad try to help me supposing the version of the jdbc driver, I put the configuration exactly equal to other project I have working pretty well and the error was the same, so I knew that the error was in my own code, for sure.

Comment: I had same error message with missing `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` on `enum` field

Comment: I am having exactly similar problem, but in my model the type is Enum, and in db it's varchar. I don't see int anywhere for that field. Not sure!

Comment: Got it! for us in the same model 2 enum values were there, one was annotated with  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING), so it was able to take the String enum, while the other field wasn't. So in the other filed after saving the enum in number format(0 for 1st, 1 for 2nd...) it was getting read properly.

Comment: Had the error also on a missing `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` (even not sure if it was the circumstance that it was only on the setter instead now on instance variable)

Comment: Noticed that the value after `:` indicates which field is cause the bad query. Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was while using `enum` inside `Entity` column. Solution was to add `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` in column definition.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a separate database schema, just change the column type to `boolean`:

```
ALTER TABLE role ALTER COLUMN admin TYPE boolean default false;
ALTER TABLE role  MODIFY admin NOT NULL;
```

and then the mapping is as simple as this:

```
@Column(name = "admin", nullable = false)
private boolean admin = false;
```

Comment: Hey @Vlad, thank you for your answer, but my column in the database is exactly like this already.


> admin boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false

Comment: Well, in that case it works just fine on my current PostgreSQL project. Make sure you use the proper JDBC driver version: `9.1-901-1.jdbc4` and the `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` dialect.

Comment: I was using the 9.2 version of postgres, now that I see in the pom file, but the database is 9.3, let's test to see if it works with version 9.3 in the pom...

Comment: Vlad, I included in my pom file exactly this version of postgresql jdbc and the error was the same... =/

I included the version 9.3 and error too

Comment: I have a similar exception but I am pretty sure my primary key is correct. Any chance you could take a look Vlad? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63231507/144578

Comment: I managed to fix the issue now but good to know that exists! Might come in useful sometime.

Comment: It surely does. When in doubt, go to Vlad Mihalcea Dot Com.

Comment: @VladMihalcea could you help me out please

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142030/how-to-map-serial-and-timestamptz-of-graphlql